# Parent div, height not set, over-sizes height by a few pixels to fit child img element height? Why?

Tags: html, css, height, parent, image

**In all major browsers**: as the question states, a parent `<div>` container (whose height is not set) over-sizes its height to fit a child `<img>` element (for instance, a 300-pixel tall image that is the only thing inside the `div`). The over-sizing is usually about 3 to 5 pixels, and appears at first as img `margin-bottom` or div `padding-bottom` might look.

However, using absolute positioning, it is clearly demonstrated that the bottom of the `div` is below the bottom of the `img`by a few pixels. It might not ruin a website's design, but it is a hurdle to overcome in certain situations. **[I have made a fairly detailed fiddle demonstrating this issue here](http://jsfiddle.net/BadzT/1/).**

- **Why is this standard practice in web browsers?**
- **Is this meant to compensate for something? It seems unnecessary.**
- **Is this a bug, or a soon-to-be antiquated feature?**

> **EDIT:** Thanks to the answerers/commentators below, I know the reason is that an `<img>` is treated by default as CSS
>   `display:inline` which preserves whitespace around the element.
>   Changing it to `display:block` completely fixes the problem by
>   eliminating whitespace around the element.

**Notes:** This over-sizing can be averted by giving the image child element a CSS property of `float:left` or `float:right`, etc., but this is a **workaround**, and as such is **not** the answer to the question. One reason this can be problematic is if you already have other `float` elements layered in front of the div child image (float overlap not allowed Firefox, Opera, IE. `float` overlapping only seems allowed in Chrome and Safari using CSS `position` settings). *Thanks!*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add display:block to your image. I think that will fix the problem.

Comment: IT WORKS. Thanks. But why? What is the display type of the `img` without `display:block`? Lol, man I hope someone somewhere appreciates what my effort demonstrates. -_-

Comment: images are naturally `inline` elements. The browser preserves whitespace around inline elements

Comment: Yeah i was just reading on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp . Thank you very much for the information, everyone! The more I understand the WHY, the better I can grasp the HOW. ;) I'm still pretty green at web design, but I'm diligently teaching myself, and this community is teaching me and so many more! <3